# CoreData and NSFetchedResultsController with merging changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I'm fighting with my first CoreData application and I stuck with several problems - I feel like I'm doing something really wrong.

On main thread I have a UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController, create with this code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)newFetchedResultsControllerWithSearch:(NSString *)searchString
{
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray* sortDescriptors = @[sort];

NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactId != 1"];

/*
 Set up the fetched results controller.
 */
// Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *callEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ContactDB" inManagedObjectContext:[[AppManager sharedAppManager] managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:callEntity];

NSMutableArray *predicateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
if(searchString.length)
{
    // your search predicate(s) are added to this array
    [predicateArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString]];
    // finally add the filter predicate for this view
    if(filterPredicate)
    {
        filterPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:filterPredicate, [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray], nil]];
    }
    else
    {
        filterPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray];
    }
}

[fetchRequest setPredicate:filterPredicate];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                                            managedObjectContext:[[AppManager sharedAppManager] managedObjectContext]
                                                                                              sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                                       cacheName:nil];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
{
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return aFetchedResultsController;
}
```

I'm doing some background downloads to update the data which is displayed inside that UITableView. According to informations I found on web I'm creating new MOC to do those changes and I'm merging it later with my main thread MOC.

```
- (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if(notification.object != [[AppManager sharedAppManager] managedObjectContext]) {
        [[[AppManager sharedAppManager] managedObjectContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }
});
}
```

For merging delegates I'm using standard Apple functions.

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
UITableView *tableView = controller == self.fetchedResultsController ? self.tableView : self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
[tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
 didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
       atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
 forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType) 
{
UITableView *tableView = controller == self.fetchedResultsController ? self.tableView : self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
switch(type)
{
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)theIndexPath
 forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
UITableView *tableView = controller == self.fetchedResultsController ? self.tableView : self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
switch(type)
{
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self fetchedResultsController:controller configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:theIndexPath] atIndexPath:theIndexPath];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
UITableView *tableView = controller == self.fetchedResultsController ? self.tableView : self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
[tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Problem 1: Notification comes through and merges are visible inside UITableView, but problem is filtering doesn't work for merges. As you can see in my filters I'm skipping contactId = 1, but when merges are being done this contact appears inside UITableView.

I'm still not sure if there is a better way to react on changes done to database on another thread - like reloading table view and refetching UITableView data.

Problem 2: When I scroll fast while it's reloading it's crashing with message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x19762a40
```

That only happens if I delete in background thread and it appears in code responsible for creating a UITableViewCell - it crashes on accessing one of properties.

EDIT

As a workaround I've made:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
UITableView *tableView = controller == self.fetchedResultsController ? self.tableView : self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
[tableView endUpdates];

[controller performFetch:nil];
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

So I'm manually performingFetch and reloadingData to filter entries again.

Here is how I construct CoreData related objects:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
if(_managedObjectModel != nil) {
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
self.managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] autorelease];
return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

self.managedObjectContext = [self createManagedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *) createManagedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType:(NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType)concurrrencyType
{
NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:concurrrencyType] autorelease];

if(concurrrencyType == NSMainQueueConcurrencyType)
{
    [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
}
else
{
    [managedObjectContext setParentContext:self.managedObjectContext];
}

return managedObjectContext;
}
```

And here is code for updating contacts:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
             NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[AppManager sharedAppManager] createManagedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

             //clear database
             NSArray* allContacts = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"ContactDB"];

             if([allContacts count] > 0)
             {
                 for (ContactDB* contact in allContacts)
                 {
                     [context deleteObject:contact];
                 }
             }

             NSArray* responseContacts = responseObject[@"contacts"];
             [responseContacts enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                 NSMutableDictionary* contactDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:obj];
                 ContactDB* contact = [[[ContactDB alloc] initWithDictionary:contactDict andContext:context] autorelease];
                 contact.order = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[order indexOfObject:contact.contactId]];
             }];

             [context save:nil];
             [[[AppManager sharedAppManager] managedObjectContext] performBlock:^{
                 [[[AppManager sharedAppManager] managedObjectContext] save:nil];
             }];

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_LOADING_STOPPED object:self userInfo:nil];
             });
         });
```

Comment: You **really** need to be checking those saves.  Pass in an error and check it.  If you don't you have the potential for a hidden error that you will not detect or properly react to.  Anytime Objective-C asks for an error pointer, set it and check it. Passing in `nil` negates any other debugging.

Comment: Yeah I know it was just for speeding up testing - I was refactoring coding 10 times to find out what's happening - but I knew it was nothing with error :)

Comment: Even then put the error code in there.  Use a macro completion app to make it easier.  I have solved more issues in code reviews by just putting the error code back in than I can count.  Even in presentation slides I put it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days of looking around I prepared a simpler example of my problem from scratch and I found a problem finally. I still don't understand why it was working from loaded database not for updates but I changed:

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactId != 1"];
```

To:

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactId != %@", @"1"];
```

I understand first one is incorrect because it's not NSString and my contactId is NSString, but why it is working when I load app - when core data loads from disk. And for merges and updates NSPredicate with != 1 was not working.

Maybe it will help someone - make sure for predicates you respect type.

Comment: This same problem was causing my `NSFetchedResultsController` to only notice deletes and not inserts when I was merging changes made in `NSPersistentContainer`'s `performBackgroundTask()` into the `viewContext` of an `NSPersistentContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating multiple MOCs, is there a reason you are not using the parent/child design?  If you are using parent/child then you do **not** need to merge changes.  That is one of the benefits of parent/child.

From the error, I suspect you are breaking the thread boundary rules.  The question is where hence my question about using parent/child.

When you hit this error, where does the break point fire at?  What line of code is responsible for triggering that error?  What thread is that line of code being fired on?

### Update

What does the predicate end up looking like at the end of this?  Have you printed the final predicate to console to take a look at it and make sure it is building the way you think it should be?  I see a lot of and/or combinations in there.

Did your crash go away with the switch to parent child?  I ask because I looked at your code for the merging and it *could* be suspect.  Better to write it as:

```
- (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[AppManaged sharedAppManager] managedObjectContext];
    [moc performBlock:^{
        [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }];
}
```

That way you are guaranteed to be on the right queue for the merge.

Comment: Hey thanks for suggestions. I tried already with parent / child but when I merge child with parent it blocks main thread for a long time and it was taking much longer in general to update (i'm working with around 5000 entries update). I had some problems with parent / child - I will change to that approach and post a code.

Comment: This error appears on code that is creating cells - when I'm trying to access one of CoreData ManagedObject properties.

Comment: what thread is the error on?  If you are not on thread zero in UI code then threading is your problem.

Comment: If you are having performance problems with P/C and threading then you should focus on solving that issue not avoiding it because you are just passing that performance hit to somewhere else.  Breaking your updates into small chunks is usually the easiest answer.

Comment: And how about problem that FetchResultController is ignoring NSPredicates on that merge ? It will be solved as well on parent / child ?

Comment: Yes, you will most likely need to save the main/UI context to get your FRC to fire properly.  Something I recommend anyway when you are doing multi-thread data manipulation.

Comment: I changed it to parent/child - but still it is showing me the entries that should be filtered out. Check my edit

Comment: What does your FRC construction look like?

Comment: Updated my question with codes for creating MOC and the code that runs update in background. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to note that you can pass `NSNotification` object posted on another thread to `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` without dispatching.

Also, in the code for updating contacts instead of dispatching you should use `performBlock:` method of `NSManagedObjectContext` since it's created with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` concurrency type.

So the idea is create `NSManagedObjectContext` with concurrency type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, and set it's parent to your main `NSManagedObjectContext`. Then you use main MOC for 'NSFetchedResultsController', and and private MOC for updating data.

```
[privateMOC performBlock:^{
    // update your data
    [privateMOC save:NULL]; // you should use NSError though
    [privateMOC.parentContext performBlock:^{
        [privateMOC.parentContext save:NULL]; // there your NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods should be fired automatically
    }];
}];
```

As you see, there is no need for dispatching.
And, you really should use ARC. I'm sure compiler more efficient than we.

**Update**

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactId != 1"];

/*
 Set up the fetched results controller.
 */
// Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"ContactDB"] autorelease];

if(searchString.length)
{
    // your search predicate(s)
    NSPredicate *searchTermPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString];
    // finally add the filter predicate for this view
    filterPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:filterPredicate, searchTermPredicate, nil]];
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get the second tip. About dispatching on main queue - I found recommendation that merge has to be done on main thread - to get UI updates properly.

Comment: I'd suggest using parent/child contexts too. I'll update my answer with it's example now.

Comment: I'm not using ARC - I had a lot of problems with ARC performance few months back on another projects - so I prefer to manually take care of that ;)

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski updated my answer. Make sure you set parent MOC.

Comment: Thanks for code. That works exactly same as mine in terms of problems :) Still NSPRedicate with contactId != 1 is completely ignored and when NSFetchedResultsController are fired the objects not meeting NSPredicates are added to UITable :(

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski you can check if the current object is contact 1 inside `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert` change, but that will be very very dirty fix. I'd encourage you play around with predicates a bit instead.

Comment: The thing is that             [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; inside controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType is pushing that into the table - and in that case NSPredicate is somehow not applied :(

Comment: Yes I know I could fix that - but that sounds extremly strange and buggy - why use NSFetchedResultsController if it's ignoring predicates on updates... that sounds like a bug for me :) For that simple filter I could do it manually but for more complicated it's gonna be a madness if predicates are not working.

Comment: Why are you checking for `filterPredicate` if you set it before? Or you didn't post full code?

Comment: In newFetchedResultsControllerWithSearch method there is predicate with @"contactId != 1" which is later assigned to fetchRequest and NSFetchedResultsController. performFetch is execute while it's created, but it looks like while merging changes it's not taken into account :( Everything is in code I pasted

Comment: Yeah sorry but that's wrong idea. THat is only for second NSFetchedResultsController and I'm having problem with my standard one when searchfilter is nil, so the code you suggested is not even used :(